# WebDavSharp server. how to use Word option share a link

Tags: c#, sharepoint, server, webdav, httplistener

I need help about the option in Microsoft Word 2013: **Share** >> *Send a link*.

**Intro**

I am using webdav technology (Project Webdav#) to set up a shared network drive. It is running in a service on a Windows Server 2012. (http://webdavsharp.github.io/)

The C# code used for listening the requests webdav/HTTP1.1 is:

```
server = new WebDavServer(new WebDavDbStore("WebDav"));
server.Listener.Prefixes.Add(Url);

IHttpListenerContext context = Listener.GetContext(_stopEvent);

//Write the response
using (BinaryWriter _outputStream = new BinaryWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
{
    _outputStream.Write(buffer);
    _outputStream.Close();
}
```

Then, I return the binary of the document Word from the webdav server to the person who browse the folder in the windows explorer mapped in the local computer (Windows 8.1 + mini-redirector). And all is working very well.

**Question**

When the distant word document is open on sharepoint, I have the option: File >> Share >> Email >> Send a link.

When I open it from my own Server Webdav, the folder is mapped locally, on the virtual drive “file:///\webdav.mydomain.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\Folder 1”, but I would like it to be mapped as my distant shared server (https:// webdav.mydomain.com/Folder 1 in this example).

Sharepoint has a similar feature, and the link is formated as https:// sharepoint.mydomain.com. 
With WebDAVSharp.Server, I expect https:// webdav.mydomain.com but I get 
file:///\webdav.mydomain.com@SSL\DavWWWRoot\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to have this URL in Office, I needed to implement the MS-WDV protocol that require the response to an OPTIONS request need to be replied with the header X-MSDAVEXT: 1.